# UML in Dia, inherit arrow diagonal?

Tags: uml, dia

Is Dia able to make the inherit arrows diagonal? E.g. I have two classes, one of it is in the middle and the other one in the upper left corner. I want the arrow to go straight to the other class, but atm it goes left and then up, with a 90° angle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dia there is not a possibility to change the line-style of predefined arrows. But you can make the line manually. At the bottom of the graphics menu you have the option to change the line style. Just choose a straight line for the beginning and the middle of the arrow and the white arrow for the ending.
To then draw this arrow you can select "Draw Line" or press "L" and then draw the line. If the white arrow is to small for you just double click the line and change the size of it.